# I am using android studio 2.1.My default hello world app is running (emulator),but it is crashing when launching on a jelly bean device

Tags: java, android

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.aman.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
}
```

Comment: Please post the error log.

Comment: post crash log  !!

Comment: are you running directly from android studio or installing unaligned apk in device??

Comment: My app is running perfectly in the marshmallow emulator of android studio 2.1..On installing (unaligned apk) on a jelly bean device it says "My Application has stopped"..